# Tornado Websockets doesn't call on_message without ping

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

This is driving me bonkers. I am using Tornado 3.2 with python 2.7.  I've tried it on both my test machine (Windows) and my Linux box.  I am just testing the waters with (what I thought would be) a dead simple chatroom application.  Here's the code thus far:

```
class LobbyWS(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self, *args):
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
        self.ping('one')
        LobbyWS.clients.append(self)
        print 'opening %s' % self

    def on_pong(self, data):
        print 'got pong', data

    def on_message(self, message):      
        print "Client %s received a message : %s" % (self, message)
        for client in LobbyWS.clients:
            client.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        print "Client %s closed." % self
        LobbyWS.clients.remove(self)
```

The code seems to work just fine.  However, if I remove the self.ping(), it stops working.  The socket appears open on the browser end, however, the on_message() function on the server is never called (same behavior in Chrome and Firefox).  Why does it seem the server has to send data on the socket before it can receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python is correct so I guess the error is on the client side which you did not provide. Be sure not to call send() before the connection is established.

Here a complete working example:

```
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.autoreload
import tornado.web

class LobbyWS(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self, *args):
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
        LobbyWS.clients.append(self)
        print 'opening %s' % self

    def on_pong(self, data):
        print 'got pong', data

    def on_message(self, message):
        print "Client %s received a message : %s" % (self, message)
        for client in LobbyWS.clients:
            client.write_message(message)

    def on_close(self):
        print "Client %s closed." % self


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("""
<html><head><script>

    console.log('starting ws connection');
  var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/lobby');

    connection.onopen = function () {
        console.log('open');
        connection.send('Hello Server');
    };

    // Log errors
    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
    };

    // Log messages from the server
    connection.onmessage = function (e) {
      console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
    };




</script></head></html>

""")


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/lobby", LobbyWS),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.autoreload.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Hope this helps.